# Test AWS SQS End Point

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have an AWS SQS queue, and for some reason my connections to the the end point are being refused.

If I try:

```
curl -Is https://sqs.[REDACTED].amazonaws.com/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]| head -1
```

I get "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" error. I suspect that this is the root cause of the issue I am having with being able to access the queue with an external application. However, I have the conditions set really broadly:

[image]

How do I know the issue I am experiencing is not a permissions issue? Is there a way for me to test the queue is actually responsive?

If so, is there a way in CURL for me to get *any* or *all* data from a message to verify I am receiving content, and then build my application around my response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following curl request:

```
curl -i https://sqs.{region}.amazonaws.com/{account}/{name}/\?Action=ReceiveMessage
```

If you want to use long-polling:

```
while true; do
  curl -i https://sqs.{region}.amazonaws.com/{account}/{name}/\?Action=ReceiveMessage\&WaitTimeSeconds\=20
done
```

See the [ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) SQS API docs for all supported parameters.

Another alternative is to use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead, which also works with authentication:

```
aws sqs receive-message --queue-url https://sqs.{region}.amazonaws.com/{account}/{name}
```